# Variables in find exec command

Tags: bash

How does the $1 work in this find command? I can't find any examples or documentation of what this is doing anywhere. This comes from a question 'Remove all file extensions in current working dir.'

```
find `pwd` -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.*}"' - '{}' \;
```

Comment: Prefer `find $(pwd) -type f …` to ```find `pwd` -type f …``` for numerous reasons.  Granted, in the present context, it doesn't matter much, but learning good habits now will benefit you when it does matter.

Comment: That's a great point! Thank you!

Comment: Actually, prefer `find "$(pwd)" ...` to make sure the literal directory name is used instead of subjecting it to word-splitting or pathname expansion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The string to be executed by `find` is

```
bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.*}"' - '{}'
```

For each file it finds, `find` will replace `{}` with the pathname of the found file:

```
bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.*}"' - '/path/to/filename.ext'
```

`bash` then executes `mv "$1" "${1%.*}"` with `$0` set to `-` (making it a login shell) and `$1` set to `/path/to/filename.ext`. After applying the substitutions, this results in

```
mv /path/to/filename.ext /path/to/filename
```

Note: `` find `pwd` `` is a complicated way to say `find .`.

Comment: Got it. Thank you! I got so caught up in the exec that I didn't realize what the bash -c was doing.

Comment: Does it really make it a login shell? I though `$0` in `bash -c` is just used as the name of the process.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/bash.1.html): "A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a `-`,  or one started with the `--login` option".

Comment: Note that the goal may or may not have been to actually create a login shell; it is common to simply put a dummy string as the first argument so that `$1` gets set correctly. Usually, you don't care what the value of `$0`.

Comment: I'm still not sure. Try this: `bash -c 'echo $0; shopt login_shell' -` - indicates that it's not a login shell. `bash --login -c 'echo $0; shopt login_shell' whatever` on the other hand _is_ a login shell, despite `$0` not starting with `-`. You can also put an `echo` statement into `.bash_profile` and see when it's executed: only with `--login`. The only time I see a login shell where `$0` actually is `-bash` is in the virtual console reachable with Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Comment: I guess the definitive answer is in the [source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c).

Comment: so there are 3 ways: `{}`,`\`pwd\``, `pwd`.