# How do i move all csv files starting from specific characters and modified in a specific week to another path?

Tags: csv, unix, directory, cron, move

I have a directory with multiple files (say */home/initialdirectory*) that has:

```
C-2343.csv
F-4455.csv
G-4433.txt
C-8788.csv
```

I want to move all .csv files that were modified between Monday 0:00:00 and Sunday 0:00:00 of the previous week and start with character "C", to another directory (say *home/initialdirectory/backup*).

I want to implement this in a cron that will be executed on Sunday 0:00:00.

Answer (score 0):

[Using this good method for using find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/848327/2162861)

[Getting dates is explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6497622/2162861)

[Expanding filenames in find command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41917456/2162861) explains the complexity of passing the filename into what amounts to a shell script.

Command below finds all files newer than last monday and not newer than sunday (could be last-sunday), the file name must start with `C` and end with `.csv`, after finding the file execute a shell and pass the found path in as argument 1 `$src` and then replace `olddir` with `newdir` in `$dst`. If no dst directory exist, create dst directory. Move the file from `olddir` to `newdir`.

```bash
gfind olddir \
-newermt "$(date -dlast-monday +%Y%m%d)" \
! -newermt "$(gdate -dsunday +%Y%m%d)" \
-name C*\.csv \
-exec bash -c \
'src=$1 && \
dst="${1/#olddir/newdir}" && \
[ -d $(dirname $dst) ] || \
mkdir -p $(dirname $dst) && \
mv $src $dst' \
bash \{\} \;
```